# Should the useRef in useEffects be 0 or 1 after after the component mounts?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Based on my understanding, useEffect runs when the components are mounted/rendered the first time. Please why is the count not 1 after the first render?

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";

function App() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const count = useRef(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    count.current = count.current + 1;
  });

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
      />
      <h1>Render Count: {count.current}</h1>
    </>
  );
}
```

I can't find an answer to this online.

Comment: Because the component has no way to know that it should re-render. Mutating the `current` property of a ref won't trigger a re-render.

Comment: @ivanatias , I mean isn't this callback function called regardless as the component mounts?

Comment: Yes, the `useEffect` fires and the ref's `current` property is being mutated but like I said, this won't trigger a re-render, that's why you don't see the updated `count.current` being rendered.

Answer (score 0):

The **value** of `count.current` is **1** after the effect ran, but the UI still shows **0** because there has not been a re-render yet.

This is one important distinction between `ref` and `state` in React: mutating a ref *does not* trigger a re-render while updating state *does*.

[This React docs page](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/referencing-values-with-refs#differences-between-refs-and-state) describes this difference in detail and includes examples of how you could solve this with `useState`.